# Function that reverse bytes of a given pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

Function parameter : 1. Void pointer 2. Number of values to be reversed (as we have multiple values in array) 3. Size of data type casted to void. Return value of function should be int.

Typecasting will be users choice weather it is integer, double or character to be passed.

I've done code till the point where pointer in the function should get values as entered by user. when my choice is an integer, the code works fine, but when my choice is double the values that I receive to pcTemp are all 0s. after I get values I can reverse the addresses on my own.

I'm a newbie with c in need of a little help. The code is as follows

```
int function(void* pPointer, int nSwapValue, int nTypeSize)
{
    int nCount = 0;
    int nQuotient = 0;
    int nIndex = 0;
    int nTemp = 0;
    int pIndex = 0;
    char *pTemp[128] = {0};
    unsigned char* pcTemp = NULL;

    if(pPointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, Input string NULL");

        return 0;
    }

    pcTemp = (unsigned char*)pPointer;

    while(nCount < nSwapValue)
    {
        printf("Value : %x\n", pcTemp[nIndex]);

        nIndex = nIndex + nTypeSize;

        nCount++;

        nQuotient = pcTemp[nIndex];
    }

    return 1;
}

void main()
{
    int aNumber[128] = {0};
    double dNumber[128] = {0};
    void* pPointer = NULL;
    int nCount = 0;
    int nTotalValues = 0;
    int nChoice = 0;

    printf("What type of value do you want to enter ?\n");

    printf("Enter 1 for integer \nEnter 2 for Double\n");

    scanf_s("%d", &nChoice);

    printf("How many values do you want to enter ?\n");

    scanf_s("%d", &nTotalValues);

    //printf("Enter %d values \n", nTotalValues);

    for(nCount = 0; nCount < nTotalValues; nCount++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter value [%d] : ", nCount);

        if(nChoice == 1)
        {
            scanf("%d", &aNumber[nCount]);
            pPointer = &aNumber;
        }

        else
        {
            scanf("%f", &dNumber[nCount]);
            pPointer = &dNumber;
        }
    }

    function(pPointer, nTotalValues, sizeof(pPointer));

    return 1;

    getch();
}
```

Comment: `reverse byte`..needs clarification, especially if data type is multi-byte. if the input can be considered as `string`, some hand-rolled implementation of `strrev()` [--> not a library function] can do the job.

Comment: Reversing is not at all an issue. maybe I used confusing words to explain . Happens alot being new to c.

Comment: @MilanTripathi, How do you tell that it works for `int`. It is not reversing the bytes at all

Comment: @Santosh I've already specified in the question that after I get the values in the function I can do it on my own.

Comment: @MilanTripathi it *sounds* like you're supposed to be reversing the *element order* of arbitrary sequence of `count` elements, each of which is size `size`. If so, you're making this harder than it needs to be, [see example](http://pastebin.com/PaZULLGz). Regardless, your `sizeof(pPointer)` is definitely wrong. That size should be established in the respective condition blocks prior.

Comment: @WhozCraig No No. I'm pretty sure its what I mentioned in the question is what I have to do. And thanks, I corrected the sizeof mistake.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, what little is mentioned in the question is unclear. The cut/paste of the assignment itself describes the setup of the function, yet states no actual *purpose* of the function itself, rather describing only the parameters and a useless return value. the only *hint* of purpose is the title, and that taken literally would reverse the physical bytes of *the address* stored in a pointer, so it isn't much help either. Sorry, but your question is simply not *clear*. (and good that you fixed your `sizeof()` issue, Santosh deserves an uptick from you for that).

Comment: @WhozCraig : Actually I wrote the question on my own and the function returns integer as a flag or a BOOL . Mind well what you call useless, 'the beauty of function' or your 'understanding'.

Comment: I'll mind well what I read. Honestly, *honestly*, read this question as if someone *other than you* wrote it and determine the clarity of the function *purpose*, how the code posted attempts to address it, and how the problem ensuing is encountered while doing so. Opinions are like arses; everyone has one, and imho, the question and its details could simply have been better. Regardless, I'm glad you solved your problem. Tis all good.

Comment: I still have that unsolved, scroll to comments in the answer by Santosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason is that `sizeof(pPointer)` would always return `4`, irrespective of the datatype it is pointing to.

Declare a variable to hold size based on the type of input and edit as below inside `for()` loop,

Also when reading `double` use `%lf`

```
    int size = 0;

    for...............
    if(nChoice == 1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &aNumber[nCount]);
        pPointer = &aNumber;
        size = sizeof(int);
    }

    else
    {
        scanf("%lf", &dNumber[nCount]);         /* changed from %f to %lf*/
        pPointer = &dNumber;
        size = sizeof(double);
    }
```

and when calling the function, use the variable `size`.

```
function(pPointer, nTotalValues, size);
```

> **Double is not stored the same as integer in the memory. 
>
>   It would be stored in the exponent form. Because of which when you try to read byte by byte from a double variable using a char pointer you will read only 0's**

For example consider :

```
int i = 100;
double d = 100;
char *c = NULL;

c = &i;    
printf("%x\n", *c);

c = &d;
printf("%x\n", *c);
```

The output would be `64` and `0` respectively

Comment: Thanks santosh. while using double I also used hardcoded size in function. size + 8 which should've worked but it didn't.

Comment: @MilanTripathi: check the updated answer. Hope this would answer you question

Comment: Thanks, but this tells me where I'm going wrong, tell me what do I have to do to correct it. And yeah I was just experimenting with float so when I changed type I forgot to change it in the code. and yes If you could give me an answer to this : suppose I want to have a third option as in float, then how do I differentiate its method of code as both are 8 bytes.

Comment: When using double enter a fraction, like 1.23, in which case `pcTemp` would not be 0. When using whole number use integer data type. When you need 8 byte datatype to store integer values then use `long long`